# Extending Node.js Modules with OOP

Tags: node.js, oop, inheritance, passport.js, prototypal-inheritance

Am I missing something, or is it just not possible to extend arbitrary Node modules like you would, say, a Java class?

#### Concrete example:

I need `passport-remember-me` to expose the `req` object to the `_issue` method. What I tried to do was to extend that function (`RememberMe.Strategy`), modify the `_issue` function, then delegate to the original parent class' function for the actual business logic:

```
  // 1: Extend RememberMeStrategy
  function IWillRememberYou (options, verify, issue) {
     RememberMeStrategy.call(this, options, verify, issue);
  }

  util.inherits(RememberMeStrategy, IWillRememberYou);

  // 2: Override some method
  IWillRememberYou.prototype.authenticate = (req, options) => {
     // Save original function
     const issue = this._issue;

     // Wrap the supplied callback so it can now be sent extra args
     this._issue = (user, issued) => {
        // Send in additional parameter
        issue(req, user, issued);
     };
  };
```

What this gives me is an empty `this` context inside `IWillRememberYou.authenticate` as well as inside `RememberMeStragety.authenticate`. Why is this happening??

#### What the parent class looks like (the third-party Node module)

```
function Strategy(options, verify, issue) {
  // ...
  passport.Strategy.call(this);

  // ...
  this._issue = issue;
}

util.inherits(Strategy, passport.Strategy);


Strategy.prototype.authenticate = function(req, options) {
   // ...

   // My end goal is to send (req, user, issued) to that callback
   this._issue(user, issued);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use arrow functions when doing OO. That's because arrow functions are deliberately designed to break how `this` works. Instead do:

```
IWillRememberYou.prototype.authenticate = function (req, options) {
  /* .. */
};
```

Remember, with arrow functions you basically bind `this` to the context where the function is defined. If you defined it outside of any function then `this` will be the global object or `undefined` if in strict mode.

What this boils down to is that arrow functions breaks inheritance.

Comment: Ah, that's what I was overlooking. Thanks!